# Php single user login

Tags: php, security, mysqli

I'm creating a simple php website with a single user (administrator) which you have to setup during the website's installation, and obviously the website will have a simple login form for the administrator. 
So my question is do i need any security precautions like password encryption or something if there's only one user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use PHP function `password_hash()` from http://php.net/manual/book.password.php to securlely generate a salted hash of the password for storing on your configuration file/database.
On the login script you may then use `password_verify()` to check provided password against the stored hash.

install.php:

```
// $password contains the chosen admin password (user input)
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// Write $hash in configuration storage
```

login.php:

```
// $inputPassword contains the type password that we have to check (user input)
// $hash contains the admin password's (retrieved from configuration storage)
if (password_verify($inputPassword, $hash)) {
    // Password OK
} else {
    // Wrong password
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to encrypt your password. Typically with a [salt](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define%3apassword%20salt&oq=define%3apassword%20salt&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3292j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Then you'll need to ensure for authentification you aren't passing that password on every request. I was just reading [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) which is pretty informative.